# AD users and groups are not populating in the Jenkins role strategy plugin user list

Tags: jenkins, plugins, redhat

I have an instance of Jenkins Cloudbees Team running on a redhat 7.4 server. I have it linked into an Active Directory using the AD jenkins plugin. This plugin is working fine and has been for months. All users in the AD have been able to login as needed.

I have recently had the Role Strategy Plugin added into the jenkins server. The roles, projects, groups and other portions of the Role Strategy Plugin appear to work just fine.

My problem is that In the list of users under the "Assign Role" page, it does not populate with any users except for myself and anonymous. My user is from AD, but no other user or group appears in the user list to assign roles to. I know for a fact the AD is working, because another individual in AD is currently logged into jenkins and working on a job configuration.

Any ideas on why the AD users are not populating in the Role Strategy plugin's user list?

Comment: Does your login have permission to see the users?

Comment: Yes. I am logged in as an administrator. I have all of the permissions on the Jenkins application.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins doesn't autopopulate those lists. You have to add them manually and make sure the groupname matches (case sensitive!). You are the only one included by default because Jenkins knows you enabled the role strategy.
Very primitive but that's what it is.